# Difference between RFS and other file systems

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext2

I have read that RFS is the basic skeleton which is needed in a computer while booting linux.
As per my knowledge File system is a directory structure for storing files.

When RFS is already there, why do we need a other file system like EXT2 and several others.And where these file systems are mounted(EXT2 or other) .

Are these several file system co exist together with RFS when pc is running.

Comment: Do you mean *root filesystem*?  It probably *is* ext4 or something like that.

Comment: Yes RFS= Root file system
SO, it means that the Directory structure of Every file system in Linux is same , be it Ext2 , EXT 3, EXT 4? .

Answer (score 0):

You mast first know what is RFS:

RFS is a Samsung file system for user space applications formatted as RFS (Robust File System). RFS is a FAT 16/32 based file system with a sort of journalling system on it. The code to build and use the RFS file system is proprietary and only used in Samsung equipment, such as TV's, BluRay players and cellphones.
So it's a different file system, and can be used in a partition and other can be used in other partition.

Answer (score 0):

On unix-like file systems, it is possible to add lots of different types of devices and logical structures to a file system, as if it were a file or directory by mounting them from a file system. One of the most common things to add to a bare-bones file system is ... another file system. This allows the computer to keep only the most essential files on the root file system, keeping it cleaner so that it is easier to clean up if something goes wrong or gets corrupted. That means that most application-level programs live on an "extended" filesystem (EXT) because the computer does not need those programs in order to turn on.

Read more about the root file system here: http://www.linfo.org/root_filesystem.html